# Easy answer to an install problem

Tags: installation

I've been running Blender 2.90.1, everything is fine.

Just downloaded the Blender 3.3.0 install file (blender-3.3.0-macos-arm64.DMG) and I get this dialog box.

[image: screenshot 1]

My mac's spec.

[image: screenshot 2]

Any idea why I can't install it?

Comment: uhm...if you have an intel processor - shouldn't you download the intel version instead of arm version?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for getting back to me. This is the version Blender directs me to and states 'mac intel' in the download in the description. The only other mac option is 'Apple Silicon' so have to assume the download filename is correct.
Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an Intel Processor, you should download the Intel version of Blender, not the ARM version. The filename when downloaded should be: `blender-3.3.0-macos-x64.dmg`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why it was forcing the download of the ARM version.
Downloaded the OS and installed
Much appreciated.